# Allow everything except Numbers in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need a Validation Rule that will allow every characters except Numbers in a specific field.Space must be allowed but field  must not be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this check

```
IS NOT NULL AND NOT LIKE "*[0-9]*"
```